# Google Maps markers not rendered correctly on Android

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, gmaps4rails

On my website I use ruby on rails and the gem gmap4rails to render my Google Maps with markers.
Now today, one of my visitors contacted me to report a problem with the rendering of the markers on his android phone. See here the result :

[image: Rendering problem of google maps on android device]

Does anybody know why the rendering of the markers gives this result?

Comment: I think we can see the problem. No need to expose your paint skills, show-off ! :P

Comment: @Aperçu sorry, that is the screenshot of the visitor:)

Comment: this kind of issues are unfortunately linked to the html/css, and I dont support this at all

Comment: @apneadiving indeed, I put a special style on an img of this page and it added also this style to the markers. I changed it to a special class and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: mayvbe it could help other people if you answer your own question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging, I discovered that I put a special style on an img on this page using the global img tag, with the fact that it  added also this style to the markers.

I changed my style to a special class to apply it and now it works.